# how to build web api parameter dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I need to call a webAPI with string array as a parameter.

I have a string array . I need to call this api from c#

```
string[] str;
str[0]= "abc";
str[1]= "xyz";
```

how can I create the api request call like given below.

```
http://localhost:59511/api/Values?str[]="abc"&str[]="xyz"
```

Comment: I would advise you to make it as a POST request with JSON body containing your array, if possible

Comment: Either create custom model binder or use solution @Craig H provided below, it's default behavior of web api for sending arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the request like so:

```
http://localhost/api/values?str=abc&str=xyz
```